# How to gracefully support Android 2.x devices in apps that use the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

I'm writing an app and I want to use the new ActionBar that is available in Android 3.x and later for Android. The app still needs to support the majority of devices out there and most are running 2.x releases.

I've configured my project so that the minSdk is set to API 8 and targetSDK is API 14.

My question is what is best practice for using new SDK features like the ActionBar and still support older devices running older builds of Android that don't support such features?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It provides backwards compatability for the ICS ActionBar, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use v7-appcompat support library.

Check here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

For setup: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html